# DDD handling Aggregate updates over time

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, aggregateroot

Using Event Sourcing, I have a domain in which aggregates should be updated from time to time. When I create an aggregate, I have an expiry time (this can be arbitrary) on it, and after that time I have to update some properties of the entity. (This can be forced using an UpdateCommand too.) I have few processes in mind:

1. After the aggregate creation, I store the aggregate ID and the expiry time in an RDBMS.
2. In a cron job I query the database for expired aggregates, and submit an UpdateCommand

Others include emitting UpdateCommands (or events?) from the read side.
Using a saga to coordinate updates, this is similar to the first. But either way, I have to store the expiry times.

So, I have to store the events and write into a database on the write side transactionally. However, I am not sure if creating a *read-side for the write-side (?)* is the correct solution in the DDD world, or is it applicable? What are the recommended solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also need to run some commands after some time expires.

For example, I need to emit a `ContractExpiredEvent` after 1 year (the `ContractAggregate` decides when but usually it is 1 year). The problem is that the Aggregate must be the one that decides when and what command to executes, so this is a Domain concern more than an Infrastructure one.

How I did that? I was inspired by [Udi Dahan's](https://youtu.be/2EDyxoS5N7M) video in which he introduce the term `Timeout`. Long story short, the Aggregate requests that a command should be send to itself after a period of time passes. It does that by yielding it from a command handler. The underlying CQRS framework gets that `scheduled command` and persists it in a special repository. Then, a `cron job` process all scheduled commands when their time comes.

Comment: I'm gonna watch that video. Storing scheduled commands seems good. But what do you mean by ''Aggregate must be the one that decides when and what command to executes''? Isn't it the client that executes commands? I use this flow mainly: http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/

Comment: @DavidSzalai I use the cqrs.nu style. Long story short the Aggregate handles commands and yield events.

Comment: oh I get it, I saw that before (I think frameworks like Axon use that), but for me going with a separate command handler seemed more clear at first

Comment: @DavidSzalai in any case, the answer applies.

Answer (score 1):

There's well compatibility between ES and DDD.

> However, I am not sure if creating a read-side for the write-side (?) is the correct solution in the DDD world, or is it applicable?

Yes, it's a part of domain aggregate in your case (if you talk about storing expiry times on write-side).

> So, I have to store the events and write into a database on the write side transactionally.

I suggest you to use the saga for writing into a db.

Answer (score 1):

[John Carmack, 1998](http://archives.seul.org/linuxgames/Oct-1998/msg00123.html):

> If you don't consider time an input value, think about it until you do -- it is an important concept

The pattern you should be looking for is that the real world (where time is) tells the aggregate the current time, and the aggregate decides whether or not to *expire itself*.

With that pattern in place, you can use any strategy you like for scheduling *when* the real world tells the aggregate what time it is.

You don't need immediately consistent scheduling in the aggregate, you just need some idempotent message handling and an "at least once" delivery process.

> the aggregate has a method which can cause an update if it is necessary based on the current time, not blindly. At some time I have to fetch the right aggregate from the store, call that method and store the changes back (if any), or retry later, right?

Yes, that's the right idea.

Notice that if you call that method twice after the expiration time, the first call will load the history, append the expiration events, and store the updated history.  The *second* call loads the history, can see that the aggregate is already expired, and retires without making any change to the history.

Comment: Oh, I did not considered this way. So, the aggregate has a method which can cause an update if it is necessary based on the current time, not blindly. At some time I have to fetch the right aggregate from the store, call that method and store the changes back (if any), or retry later, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use bi-temporal event sourcing. When events are stored, there are two dates:

- the date when the event is added to the database (`createdAt`)
- the date when the event has to be applied (`validFrom`)

The events are then applied in the order defined by `validFrom` property.

Using this, you can:

- "fix the past" by adding a new event (`createdAt = now` and `validFrom = now - x`)
- schedule events in the future by adding a new event (`createdAt = now` and `validFrom = now + y`)

I suggest to watch this great video of Thomas Pierrain at DDD Europe 2018: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzekp1RuZbM